# html5 sound loadeddata event issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

In chrome latest version, sometimes loadeddata event got triggered after 10 / 20 / N minutes. Can't identify the reason for this issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var audio = new Audio("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3");
audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
 console.log("loadeddata triggered");
 audio.play();
});

audio.addEventListener('error', function failed(e) {
 alert("Error while load the sound | "+e.target.error.code);
},true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one tell the reason for this.

Comment: Anyone knows the cause?

Comment: loadeddata event not working propery. Please suggest your comments.